# Operand should countain 1 column(s) on SELECT INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to run a SELECT query on achievement system i'm creating for a game.

The database has a "timer_achievement" table, which are just static achievements with activation values.

It also has a "timer_player_achievement" table, which has the information about the achievement progress for each player and achievement.

I'm trying to run a query to get all the achievements that match a criteria, it should return 3 columns; id, name and points, however, it won't let me get more than one and responds with the error

`Operand should countain 1 column(s)`

The query i'm trying to run is the following:

```
SELECT (name, id, points) FROM timer_achievements 
 INNER JOIN timer_player_achievements
    ON timer_achievements.achievement_group = timer_player_achievements.achievement_group
 WHERE timer_achievements.activation_value <= timer_player_achievements.value 
 AND timer_player_achievements.obtained = false 
 AND timer_player_achievements.player_steamid = 'STEAM_1:0:78056913'
 GROUP BY timer_achievements.id;
```

Here's some info about each table:

[Achievement Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWgjB.png)

[Player Achievement Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLSki.png)

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data on older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Tip of today: table aliases! I.e. Do `... FROM timer_achievements ta ... ON ta.achievement_group = ...` to save some typing and make the query easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for both tips! Will check how to correct it after i deal with the columns problem, since the same query with just SELECT(name) instead of SELECT(name, id, points) works

Comment: ()'s are not needed on the select.  Just `SELECT name, id, points FROM`

Comment: Hey it actually was that, thanks! Feel free to submit it as answer so i can mark it